# Javascript parsing json date timezone mismatch causes wrong date to display

Tags: javascript, json, date, timezone-offset

The displaying of a javascript-parsed date is different based on the timezone of the machine loading the page.

```
SERVER TIME: EST
MACHINE #1 TIME: EST - shows proper date
MACHINE #2 TIME: EST - shows proper date
MACHINE #3 TIME: PST - shows one day earlier 
MACHINE #4 TIME: PST - shows one day earlier
```

I'm wondering how to parse a JSON date such that the time zone will not be a factor.  Here's my current code:

```
var jsonDate = "/Date(1341633600000)/";
var formattedDate = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
return formattedDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + formattedDate.getDate() + "/" + formattedDate.getFullYear();
```

What's the best approach to ignore the timezone offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with **parsing** the dates. You're sending a UTC timestamp to the client, and the client is (correctly) reflecting the date in local terms.

You can always use the `getUTCxxx` methods (`getUTCDate()`, `getUTCMonth()`, `getUTCFullYear()`) to make the page show the date as UTC. Alternatively, you could convert the timestamp to a date string on the server in its local time zone, so that the client time zone wouldn't figure into it at all.

Comment: HI @Pointy I just publish this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324955/deserializing-json-dates-timezone-less

Do you know how can I solve this?? Think its related to this answer. Thanks