# Deserializing JSON dates timezone-less

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

I have a problem that is breaking my head since yesterday and don't know how to deal with it.

- **I have a date field in my database that contains the following value:**

[image]

- **Then my application get the value and send that to my web form.** (the value still the same :) thats fine!!

[image]

- **In client side I put a break with a javascript alert to see the value that is comming from JSON** (the value still the same :) thats fine!!

[image]

The code in client side for the alert is this:

```
// transaction json model
var jsonTransaction = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.Model.Transaction))); 
alert(new Date(parseInt(jsonTransaction.Date.substr(6))));
```

- **Now when I send back the value to the server this is what I get**

[image]

- **And finally after deserialization of the JSON my date time is wrong!! instead of Day 7 its now Day 8???????**

[image]

This is the code for deserializing:

```
public JsonResult SaveBill(string jsonTransaction, string jsonTranDetails)
{
    _appState = this.AppState;
    JsonResult returnVal = returnVal = Json(
       new { Success = true }
    );

var transaction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BillTransaction>(jsonTransaction, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Any clue on how to solve this issue with dates, I should get the same date because I didn't change anything. Hope someone can guide me for a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use Newtonsoft's JSON.NET, this problem goes away.  The new web API stuff with ASP.NET MVC 4 uses the same parser.

Comment: This should discuss all you need to know: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Comment: The only way I can get the same date is doing this on server side:
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BillTransaction>(jsonTransaction, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat, DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local });

But dont know if using DateTimeZoneHandling.Local its ok??

Comment: It depends on your server-side deserialization code.  That JSON encoding as a string - `"Date(1341706634733)"` - is being interpreted by something in your server-side code. That timestamp is for your correct date. There's no standard way to encode dates in JSON, so it depends on how that `JsonConvert` code works. It *appears* that the deserializer code is interpreting the timestamp as being relative to your local time instead of as a UTC timestamp.

Comment: I think this is wrong:  `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` but I'm not familiar with that software. There should be an option to set that to UTC, so I'd try that.

Comment: I just set to UTC but then the date I get is not the same. I get + 1 day. :(

Answer (score 0):

Java script use universal time when it parse the date as currentdate = new Date(123232) 
so when you send date to client convert it to ISO date such as 
make sure the date is in UTC before convering it to strong .

```
return String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ}", dt);
```

bty I already created JSON Converted to override  any date serialization to client side to use the above function .